# Why do execution times differ between SQL statistics and profiler?

Tags: c#, sql, postman, sql-execution-plan

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I have a query that is taking more time than I would like to return.  I first noticed the issue while testing my API with postman.  The request selects data from a view and returns to the client.

When I place the request via postman with the profiler running the response time for the query is 2168ms.  I understand that in SQL 2014 the 'duration' column in the profiler window is displayed in milliseconds.

When I copy the statement that is executed from the profiler and run it directly in SQL with 'SET STATISTICS TIME ON' I am getting am elapsed time of 342 ms.

It seems strange to me that there is such a disparity in how long the same exact query takes to execute.  The only difference is the first request being run on SQL server directly from a new query window with the pasted 'exec sp_executesql' statement.

The result from the profiler with a response time of 2168 more closely match my experience calling the API via postman.

Why does the query take so much longer to execute when via a service from postman, than when executed in a new query window?  The SQL that is being executed in both instances is identical.

What can I do to further troubleshoot and ultimately resolve this issue?  I believe this query should be returning in under 1 second as it does in the query editor window when executed directly.  As previously stated I copied the statement from the profiler so that I could compare the execution and am getting two different results in terms of execution time.

**EDIT**

*Check out this Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?*

I'll give it a look, thanks for the resource.  I'm not positive it's apples to apples but I'm sure to learn something even if I strike out.  I considered parameter sniffing, but am already using EXEC sp_executesql.

*How much data is being returned by the query?*

The query returns 2,513 rows of data.  According to postman the response size is 2.84 MB.

*Can you show us the query being executed?* 
Sure, here is the query being executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  [PortalId], [UserId], [ItemId], [ItemTypeId], [Timezone], [Type], [FirstName], [LastName], [Name], [Description], [Price], [Hours], [IsShipped], [Status], [CourseUrl], [Progress], [CertificateUrl], [IsLaunched], [CompletionType], [Score], [TimeSpentSeconds], [FirstLaunchDateUtc], [LastActivityDateUtc], [EnrollmentDateUtc], [ExpirationDateUtc], [CompletedDateUtc], [Id], [CreatedOnUtc], [ModifiedOnUtc], [DeletedOnUtc], [CreatedBy], [ModifiedBy], [DeletedBy] FROM api.EnrollmentsDataView WHERE  ( [DeletedOnUtc]  IS NULL    AND   [PortalId] = @portalid0 ) ',N'@deletedonutc0 nvarchar(4000),@portalid0 bigint',@deletedonutc0=NULL,@portalid0=1
```

I am selecting from a view that I've created to join several tables together.  Anticipating the follow-up question, here is the code for the view:

```
SELECT Enrollments.[Id]
      ,Enrollments.[PortalId]
      ,Enrollments.[UserId]
      ,Enrollments.[ItemId]
      ,Items.ItemTypeId
      ,Timezones.Code as Timezone
      ,ItemTypes.Name as [Type]
      ,HlUsers.FirstName
      ,HlUsers.LastName
      ,Items.Name 
      ,Items.[Description]
      ,Items.Price
      ,Items.[Hours]
      ,Items.IsShipped    
      ,StatusTypes.Name as [Status]
      ,Enrollments.[CourseUrl]
      ,Enrollments.[Progress]
      ,Enrollments.[CertificateUrl]
      ,Enrollments.[IsLaunched]
      ,Enrollments.[CompletionType]
      ,Enrollments.[Score]
      ,Enrollments.[TimeSpentSeconds]
      ,Enrollments.[FirstLaunchDateUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[LastActivityDateUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[EnrollmentDateUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[ExpirationDateUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[CompletedDateUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[CreatedOnUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[CreatedBy]
      ,Enrollments.[ModifiedOnUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[ModifiedBy]
      ,Enrollments.[DeletedOnUtc]
      ,Enrollments.[DeletedBy]
  FROM Enrollments
  INNER JOIN Items
  ON Enrollments.ItemId = Items.Id
  INNER JOIN HlUsers
  ON HlUsers.Id = Enrollments.UserId
  INNER JOIN HlPortals
  ON HlPortals.Id = Enrollments.PortalId
  INNER JOIN StatusTypes
  ON StatusTypes.Id = Enrollments.StatusTypeId
  INNER JOIN ItemTypes 
  ON ItemTypes.Id = Items.ItemTypeId
  LEFT JOIN Timezones
  ON Timezones.Id = COALESCE(Enrollments.TimezoneId, HlUsers.TimezoneId, HLPortals.DefaultTimezoneId)
```

I am running the view and specifying that I only want results where the PortalId = 1 AND the DeletedOnUtc IS NULL.

*You can run SQL profiler and see how much time it takes for SQL server to process your request (issued via api call). sp_execute_sql vs just executing the statement are two different beasts*

Thanks for the suggestion.  I ran the query in SQL with the profiler running.  The duration in the profiler this time is 493ms.  This would match my expectations, but doesn't resolve the question of why the query takes so much longer to run when measured through the profile and executed via PostMan/.Net.

*As for how to optimize ad hoc query statement - it is really broad topic; you can learn the basic - for example here pluralsight.com/courses/… and ask follow-up questions :)*

I could certainly use some brushing up on sql optimization but I am not a complete novice in this regard either.  I'm utterly baffled by why there is such a difference in the duration of the query's execution depending on how it is triggered.  When executed directly the performance is fine so following the execution plan and making changes doesn't seem worthwhile until I can better understand what is happening here.  That said, I'm certain reviewing this course when I have the time will be worthhwile.  Thanks for the suggestion!

**Edit #2**

Here is the code that is run via SQL and via PostMan as viewed from the profiler:

SQL: CPU:94 Reads:5537 Duration: 384 (matches duration in SQL)

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  [PortalId], [UserId], [ItemId], [ItemTypeId], [Timezone], [Type], [FirstName], [LastName], [Name], [Description], [Price], [Hours], [IsShipped], [Status], [CourseUrl], [Progress], [CertificateUrl], [IsLaunched], [CompletionType], [Score], [TimeSpentSeconds], [FirstLaunchDateUtc], [LastActivityDateUtc], [EnrollmentDateUtc], [ExpirationDateUtc], [CompletedDateUtc], [Id], [CreatedOnUtc], [ModifiedOnUtc], [DeletedOnUtc], [CreatedBy], [ModifiedBy], [DeletedBy] FROM api.EnrollmentsDataView WHERE  ( [DeletedOnUtc]  IS NULL    AND   [PortalId] = @portalid0 ) ',N'@deletedonutc0 nvarchar(4000),@portalid0 bigint',@deletedonutc0=NULL,@portalid0=1

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

Postman: CPU:47 Reads:5581 Duration: 3403 (matches duration in SQL)

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  [PortalId], [UserId], [ItemId], [ItemTypeId], [Timezone], [Type], [FirstName], [LastName], [Name], [Description], [Price], [Hours], [IsShipped], [Status], [CourseUrl], [Progress], [CertificateUrl], [IsLaunched], [CompletionType], [Score], [TimeSpentSeconds], [FirstLaunchDateUtc], [LastActivityDateUtc], [EnrollmentDateUtc], [ExpirationDateUtc], [CompletedDateUtc], [Id], [CreatedOnUtc], [ModifiedOnUtc], [DeletedOnUtc], [CreatedBy], [ModifiedBy], [DeletedBy] FROM api.EnrollmentsDataView WHERE  ( [DeletedOnUtc]  IS NULL    AND   [PortalId] = @portalid0 ) ',N'@deletedonutc0 nvarchar(4000),@portalid0 bigint',@deletedonutc0=NULL,@portalid0=1
```

**EDIT #3**
I turned on Showplan Text (Unencoded) in the profiler and both the query triggered from postman and the query triggered from sql have the same exact execution plan.

What is going on here?

Comment: check out this [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: You can run SQL profiler and see how much time it takes for SQL server to process your request (issued via api call). sp_execute_sql vs just executing the statement are two different beasts

Comment: As for how to optimize ad hoc query statement - it is really broad topic; you can learn the basic - for example here https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sqlserver-optimizing-adhoc-statement-performance and ask follow-up questions :)

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments and suggestions.  I've updated my question to provide answers to as many questions as possible.  Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Much of the slowness is likely that the data needs to travel from the SQL Server to the web server, **then** from the web server to Postman. I am guessing as part of the process the web server does some kind of processing on it (e.g. converts it to JSON)?

Comment: I am not measuring the time it takes to Map and Process the request.  The profiler measures the amount of time it takes for the generated query to execute.  The profiler also does not know about Postman...